# Website gallery lagging

Tags: javascript, html, gallery

I have this gallery at - http://www.zahabiaresort.com/gallery.html - problem is it loads too slow. I know I have a lot of images to load on a single page but I'm trying to find a way to make then load only on request. I've noticed the scrollbar increases which tends to make the website a bit lagy.

Any ideas?

Comment: load them dynamically by ajax, and call any javascript required by them after they have been loaded (on success)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use AJAX and create some button(or something else) and ask user to click or hover it,  keep your all the images at your server.

you can use something like this...

```
<button class="btn" onClick="callAJAX('your_image.jpg','div_name','<img src=some_loading_graphics.gif>')">
```

here attach your AJAX file into your html file.